# Join contigous tokens if the token includes "@" char

Tags: python, if-statement

Right now I've implemented serveral `if`s to specify each condition, once the case is specified:

1. strip `@` (`@` only appears at the end of a token)
2. join with the following word
3. replace the afterwards tokens with the newly created token

But as you see (from the code), it's very repetitive, could anyone suggest a more concise way to present the code?

A snapshot of the code:

```
   # str2_tokens is the tokenized sentence
   for i in range(len(str2_tokens)):
        if "@" in str2_tokens[i] and "@" in str2_tokens[i+1] and "@" in str2_tokens[i+2]:
            str2_tokens[i] = str2_tokens[i].strip("@") + str2_tokens[i+1].strip("@") +\
                             str2_tokens[i+2].strip("@") + str2_tokens[i+3].strip("@")
            str2_tokens[i+1] = str2_tokens[i]
            str2_tokens[i+2] = str2_tokens[i]
            str2_tokens[i+3] = str2_tokens[i]

        if "@" in str2_tokens[i] and "@" in str2_tokens[i+1]:
            str2_tokens[i] = str2_tokens[i].strip("@") + str2_tokens[i+1].strip("@") +\
                             str2_tokens[i+2].strip("@")
            str2_tokens[i+1] = str2_tokens[i]
            str2_tokens[i+2] = str2_tokens[i]

        if "@" in str2_tokens[i]:
            str2_tokens[i] = str2_tokens[i].strip("@") + str2_tokens[i+1].strip("@")
            str2_tokens[i+1] = str2_tokens[i]
```

**Edited**

For instance:

Case 1: input is `paper and board â€” determination of the ink absorb@@ ency` and would like to obtain an output of `paper and board â€” determination of the ink absorbency absorbency`, `absorbency` repeated twice since two tokens've got combined.

Case 2: input is `related substance in f@@ ti@@ bam@@ zone can be determined with this method` and would like to obtain an output of `related substance in ftibamzone ftibamzone ftibamzone ftibamzone can be determined with this method`, `ftibamzone` repeated 4 times since 4 tokens've got combined.

Number of tokens with `@` could be any.

Comment: Can you pleafe first explain what you exactly aim to do? It is not very clear to me right now. What is the input? what is the *expected output*?

Comment: Pls provide the Input and its required Output

Comment: If the code is already working, requests for improvements belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `range(len(str2_tokens))` should be `range(len(str2_tokens)-3)` since you do things with  `str2_tokens[i+3]`

Comment: Is it really correct that tokens get joined if they contain a `@` anywhere, but the `@` only gets removed if it was the first or last character of the token?  That seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: please check your spelling for output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright , this is a litte repetitive but should do it

```
   result = ''
   c = 0
   for i in str2_tokens.split():
       if '@' in i:
           c+=1
           result += ''.join(i.split('@'))
       else:
           result += (i+' ')
           result += (result.split(' ')[-2]+' ')*c
           c=0
   result = result[:-1]
```

**Result**

related substance in ftibamzone ftibamzone ftibamzone ftibamzone can be determined with this method

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve what you want with this list comprehension and join:

```
"".join([token.strip("@") for token in str2_tokens])
```

E.g.

```
>>> x = ["@a", "b@", "c"]
>>> "".join([y.strip("@") for y in x])
'abc'
```

Comment: My apologies, the previous output wasn't right. Could you please take another look at the updated output?

Comment: apparently , you have to delete the space after '@' also

Comment: @Logan what are you actually trying to do here? looks like some kind of text/language special character format mixup? There might be simpler ways to solve this

Comment: @voiDnyx The mixup is the results got from `word segmentation`, I'd like to map each position to its part-of-speech.